# stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding adds unexpected characters?

Tags: nsstring, nsurl, nsstringencoding

I'm having a hard time getting my `NSURL` to work, when I create the final string before converting to `URL` it adds unwanted character to the end of the string, why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
NSString *remotepathstring = [[NSString alloc] init];
remotepathstring=newdata.remotepath;
NSLog(@"remotepathstring = %@",remotepathstring);

NSString *remotepathstringwithescapes = [remotepathstring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"remotepathstring = %@",remotepathstringwithescapes);

remotepathURL =[NSURL URLWithString:remotepathstringwithescapes];
NSLog(@"RemotePathUrl=%@",remotepathURL);
```

Log outputs as follows:

```
"remotepathstring = http://nalahandthepinktiger.com/wp-content/uploads/nalah-sheet-5.pdf‎"

"remotepathstring = http://nalahandthepinktiger.com/wp-content/uploads/nalah-sheet-5.pdf%E2%80%8E"

"RemotePathUrl=http://nalahandthepinktiger.com/wp-content/uploads/nalah-sheet-5.pdf%E2%80%8E"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence `%E2%80%8E` is a Unicode `LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK`. This is present in your original `remotepathstring`, but invisible when printed out via `NSLog`.

The question becomes: how does `newdata.remotepath` get populated in the first place? Somewhere along the line it sounds like you need to perform some extra cleanup of input strings to strip out such a character.

Unrelated to the core question, it would seem you're a newcomer to Objective-C. This code is redundant and wasteful:

```
NSString *remotepathstring = [[NSString alloc] init];
remotepathstring=newdata.remotepath;
```

You create a string, only to immediately throw it away and replace it with another. If you're not using ARC, this has the additional problem of leaking! Instead do:

```
NSString *remotepathstring = newdata.remotepath;
```

Comment: newdata.remotepath is populated from an sqlite database as follows:        `newdata.remotepath = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(st,1)];`

Comment: Then you need to sanitise these strings as they go into your database, or on the way out

Comment: is there a recommended method to doing this? I can do it as they get retrieved.

Comment: Nothing especially comes to mind. This is not something I've ever come across before, which suggests you need to ask yourself how such strings are making it into your database in the first place